# Tileable Building UV mapping problem

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

Right now, I am making a building in Blender that can be tiled but I am having trouble unwrapping the UVs for the model. I have used Blender for quite awhile now but I am still not entirely familiar with it, especially in unwrapping UVs. While I do think I have kind of wrapped my head around it, there are some things that I still do not understand.

I have attached a photo as well as the .blend file for the model.
[image: Tileable Building Screenshot]
[MelbourneBrickBuilding.blend](https://blenderartists.org/forum/attachment.php?attachmentid=487825&d=1497495038)

I need to know how I can go about unwrapping the top of the model that has been highlighted. If you look closely at some of the faces, particularly the one at the very bottom in the middle, the grid has sort of been warped across one corner to the other. Why is this happening? I also cannot figure out why some of the other faces appear warped and stretched as well. I just cannot seem to be able to mark the right seams in order to fix it.

Can somebody please help?
Thanks!

Goolog

Comment: Have you applied "scale"? What method of unwrapping are you using?

Comment: If those faces are quads they should be unwrapped as straight islands instead of squashed zigzag on the UV map. You can try Follow Active Quads or assign seams on the corners of the selected part and unwrap.

Answer (score 1):

The less planar the shape is in 3D the more distortion their unwrap will result in the UV island. While planning and marking the seams always try to imagine how easy it would be to fold the shape out of paper. After all you can fold a flat shape into 3D cube perfectly, but only if you get the seams right.

That being said if you add seams in the corners of the top part you can get pretty good unwrap results. Here I further corrected some irregularity by first unwrapping all the top row quads without seams and pinning (P key) the straight line in the UV editor to guide the unwrapping algorithm. Taking from here you could also scale the vertical ends to be on same axis if that suits your purpose (better for lightmap, less accurate for texture).

[image: Unwrapped with pinned vertices]

Unwrapping isn't the only option for UVs though. A quick and dirty way to map non-organic shapes with OK results is to use "cube project" or use multiple "project from view" commands. If you got a lot of work to do, you might want to take advantage of this and only bother with more precise and time consuming methods when it makes a big difference.

[image]

Learning UV mapping takes time but hopefully this gives you a some initial clue on how unwrapping works.

Answer (score -1):

This might be a very inadequate answer as I've never touched UVs in blender. But I suspect a simple planar map would do the trick.

Comment: How do I apply a planar map?